# oracle sql table creation error %s: invalid identifier"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Any idea why I am getting the below error while creating table on Oracle DB ?

SQL

```
create table tst(01_ITEM varchar2(100) );
```

Error
Error report -

```
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: An identifier (the column name) can't start with a digit. (Unless delimited as `"01_ITEM"`, but I'd chose another column name.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle database object names cannot begin with a digit.  You should avoid creating such column names.  If you *must* do this, then escape the column name using double quotes:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tst ("01_ITEM" varchar2(100));
```

Comment: It should be noted, that quotes not only allow additional characters inside the identifier, but also keeps identifier's case.